# Find out if wlan0 device is busy

Tags: networking, wifi, raspbian, nmcli

I'm working on a Java project for the raspberry pi that requires some networking functionality. For this I use nmcli through a Process. However, I noticed that when trying to create a new connection (with a wrong password) sometimes the error message would be:

```
Error: No  network with SSID <nameofSSID> found.
```

I tracked this down to the fact that if you call:

```
sudo iwlist wlan0 scanning
```

Shortly after trying to create a connection it will return:

```
wlan0     Interface doesn't support scanning : Device or resource busy
```

To solve this I figured I could just check if the device was busy before creating a new connection, however I have not been able to find the appropriate command.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I could come was:

```
nmcli -t -g GENERAL.STATE dev show wlan0
```

Sadly this is a mix of a number and text, but still requires minimal processing.